# Django: substitute unique_together with UniqueConstraint

Tags: django, unique-constraint

I am trying to enforce a constraint upon a `Vote` model in my Django application, namely that a user cannot vote more than once the same object.

To do so I am using `unique_together`:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    vote = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=VOTES, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="user_votes")
    definition = models.ForeignKey(Definition, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="definition_votes")

    class Meta:
        # Ensure user cannot vote more than once.
        unique_together = ["user", "definition"]
```

This works, I think.

However, in Django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together) for `unique_together` it is noted that

> `UniqueConstraint` provides more functionality than
> `unique_together`. `unique_together` may be deprecated in the future.

How can I substitute the above code using `unique_together` with code using `UniqueConstraint`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply add a [`UniqueConstraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) instead:

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                 fields=['user', 'definition'], 
                 name='unique_vote'
            )
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest confusion is the `UniqueConstraint` documentation can be arrived at directly from `unique_togther`, but it skips the [Metas.constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.constraints) documentation:

> ### constraints
>
> ##### Options.constraints
>
> ###### A list of constraints that you want to define on the model:
>
> ```
> from django.db import models
>
> class Customer(models.Model):
>     age = models.IntegerField()
>
>     class Meta:
>         constraints = [
>             models.CheckConstraint(check=models.Q(age__gte=18), name='age_gte_18'),
>         ]
> ```

The sample code quickly tells you how to use the constraints.